# In ngRepeat automatically including $$hashKey

Tags: angularjs

I have searched for a solution, I have tried all but I didn't find a solution.

In my code, I get an array from the database via ajax.

I am getting correct array, like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"product 1","image":null},{"id":"2","name":"product 2","image":null},{"id":"3","name":"product 3","image":null}];
```

but when I use it in `ng-repeat` it adds `$$hashKey`. Because of this, I am getting an error in my vendor.js file:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

I have tried all

```
  angular.copy($scope.myArray);
  angular.toJson($scope.myArray);
  JSON.stringify($scope.myArray);
```

And I have also tried:

```
  <div ng-repeat="smallArray in myArray track by $id($index)">
```

This method removes that `$$hashKey`, but it returns as a string.

For example:

```
       $scope.ans = angular.toJson($scope.myArray);
```

is equal to

```
 $scope.ans = '[{"id":"1","name":"product 1","image":null},{"id":"2","name":"product 2","image":null},{"id":"3","name":"product 3","image":null}]';
```

this is my html

```
    <div class="slide-wrap" ng-repeat="smallArray in myArray">
        <div class="slide__content-wrap">
          <h1 class="title">{{smallArray.name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide__content-wrap__inside show-for-large-up">
       <p class="description">{{smallArray.image}}</p>
         <a class="btn btn--transparent--red" href="/premium-ice-cream">view 
             all flavors</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone refer me how can I get an array with the removal of `$$hashKey` this

Comment: Provide with your `ng-repeat` HTML here

Comment: added my html part

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS adds a `$$hashKey` attribute to your objects to keep track of your changes if no `track by` isset inside your `ng-repeat` directive. Simply try to use `ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id"` and you will be fine. In that way AngularJS uses this "unique" value for its internal tracking.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id">
       {{ item | json }}
   </div>
   <br />
   <div ng-repeat="item in hashData">
       {{ item | json }}
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <button ng-click="track()">
    Click me to log
   </button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "product 1",
    "image": null
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "product 2",
    "image": null
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "product 3",
    "image": null
  }];


  $scope.hashData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "product 1",
    "image": null
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "product 2",
    "image": null
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "product 3",
    "image": null
  }];


  $scope.track = function () {
    console.log($scope.data);
    console.log($scope.hashData);
  }


});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8m1tqqz/)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution bro.